# What does State of Art Result means in context of ML/DL

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Wondering what it means to have a state of art result.Is it a relative term or a standard?

For Exmaple:
If I have developed 2 models one with higher accuracy can i say i have achieved state of art result? Or until and unless, I beat the top performer model in the world?

Comment: Let's say you decided that you wanted to build a computer from scratch and build one that performs like a computer from 1980. Then you try again and build one that performs like a computer from 1990. Is your second attempt a state-of-the-art computer in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

It means it has the current highest result.

Comment: So if i have developed 2 models one with higher accuracy can i say i have achieve state of art result? Or until and unless i beat the top performer model in the world?

Comment: Top performer model.